# Filtering Mutable Array using NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I have an MutableArray with 6 sub arrays and many subarrays within each subarray[image: Click here for screenshot] 
Each array contains details of the Station......(there are 146 arrays
altogether)

My Goal is to filter the array with "Name", but at the same time I want to extract remaining details too. I'm trying using predicate method but it is failing.

My searchResults array should be having the filtered Arrays with details of station on bases of "Name". Can someone help me in achieving this? Thanks in advance.

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText{


NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY Name CONTAINS[cd] %@",searchText];
_searchResults = [ _stationsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

}


- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(nullable NSString *)searchString{

[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: "it is failing" What does that mean? Please say what you expect and what actually happens.

Comment: i want my Searchresults array to have filtered sub-arrays.

Comment: But that might have nothing to do with the predicate. Is `_searchResults` coming out the way you expect, or not?

Comment: if u see the image that i attached, it has key: Name = "Metro Center", i want to filter using this name, there are like 146 such objects, from which i want to filter name.

Comment: To be more clear, i'm using an API to fill the tableViewCells, each cell is having the value "Name", i want to implement search option, where user enters the "Name", and he gets remaining details.

Comment: To be more clear, don't throw your whole project at the wall and say "it doesn't work". Debug! Figure out where things are going wrong and ask about _that_.

Comment: @vinod kumar add your cellforrawatindexpath method code

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this!!!

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface StationDetail : NSObject

        @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

    @end

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // Initialize 
        stationsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        NSArray *stationName = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Chennai", @"Bangalore", @"Kochi", @"Mumbai", @"Delhi", @"Hyderbad", @"Pune", @"Agra", @"Jaipur", nil];

        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            NSMutableArray *substationsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
             for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                 StationDetail *station = [[StationDetail alloc] init];
                 [station setName:[stationName objectAtIndex:index]];
                 [substationsArray addObject:station];
                 index++;

             }
            [stationsArray addObject:substationsArray];
        }


    }


    -(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText{
        // only one parameter of the object need to be filtered
        NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@",searchText]; // name is object key name 
        NSArray *searchResults = [ stationsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[searchResults count]);

    }

    -(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
        [self filterContentForSearchText:searchBar.text];
    }
```

Comment: No i cant do this, i need to apply filter on the Stations array it self, according to your code you are creating a new array exclusively for names and then applying filter to it. here my case is my array is having 146 objects, each object is having many keys, including name. i need to apply filter on name,  if i create separate array for names, i cannot use segue.

Comment: Just create a one more array like stations array. You could use the new array for segue. Keep all values in the existing array and use existing array for only filtering values.

Comment: yeh have to try this was. Thanks for your time :) . Can you share your e-mail ID? have some doubts with iOS. thank you.

Comment: @vinodkumar vigneshuvi@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText{

 allResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name CONTAINS[cd] %@",searchText];


 //used for loop to check all sub-arrays.

for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
     _searchResults = [ _stationsArray[i]   filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    [allResults addObjectsFromArray:_searchResults];
}


}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(nullable NSString *)searchString{




[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString];
return YES;
}
```